# Launcher icon too small

Tags: android

The launcher icon of my app is downsized, it's smaller than the other icons. I even tried to copy the launcher icon from my other app and when I put these apps (with the exact same icon) next to each other, one icon is smaller.

Both apps have the same minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. It's quite weird, what could possibly be the problem?

I tried reinstall, phone restart and two launchers, the default Moto G launcher and Google's KitKat launcher.

Comment: what is the dimension of the icon ? which drawable folder you use ?

Comment: I have xhdpi (96x96) and hdpi (72x72) versions.

Comment: Have you saved a similar icon in the `drawable-mdpi` and `drawable-xxhdpi` directories with the relevant dimensions?

Comment: To mdpi yes, I just tried that, didn't solve it. I copied the icons from my other app (which has mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi), where it works.

Comment: Check if you added a library or a project to your project has a resource folder contains a smaller icon it may override your project resource icon.

Answer (score 0):

Google launcher uses `xxxhdpi` drawable directory (192x192) to display app icons.

Plus, make sure you dont have an big padding transparent pixels around the icon shape,
I suggest you to use `Image Assets` to generate your app launcher icon. it comes with `Android Studio` and `Eclipse`.

> File -> New -> Image Assets

Comment: Thanks, but 1) my other app that has mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi versions works fine 2) this app has *the exact same icons* 3) the icon is downsized in the original Moto G launcher too.

Comment: then, if you use eclipse. clean the project, restart eclipse then clean. uninstall the app. then run it

Comment: I use Android Studio and tried cleaning the project, restarting the IDE,  restarting the phone and reinstalling the app.

Comment: out of ideas, sorry. just double check icons size

Comment: "Google launcher uses xxxhdpi drawable directory (192x192) to display app icons" -- only on certain screen densities. It generally picks one density bucket higher than the actual screen density.

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault, the icon simply had too much padding, it wasn't downsized. The other app had a v14 version of the icons with less padding and I copied the normal versions not noticing the v14 directory.